# Get only public methods of a class using Java reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I'm trying to use reflection to grab all public methods that are declared explicitly in the class (so `c.getMethods()` won't work since it grabs superclass methods too). I can use

```
Method[] allMethods = c.getDeclaredMethods();
```

to grab methods from just that class, but I only want to use public ones.

At this point, I'm trying to grab modifiers and do certain actions based on this, but for some reason the modifier value shown in the debugger and the modifier value output isn't the same. For example, I have a private `getNode` method that, while the "modifiers" value appears as `2` in the debugger, it outputs as `"1"` when I do `System.out.println(c.getModifiers())`. Weird. Is there another way to get just public methods, or am I missing something obvious? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Class.getMethods() will return all public methods (also inherited)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

I don't know how you are using [`Modifier`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Modifier.html), but here's how it's meant to be used

```
Method[] allMethods = Test.class.getDeclaredMethods();
for (Method method : allMethods) {
    if (Modifier.isPublic(method.getModifiers())) {
        System.out.println(method);
        // use the method
    }
}
```