# deserialize JSON into dymanically loaded class file

Tags: java, json, reflection, jackson, classloader

I have generated POJO's from Schema in JSON response, compiled and loaded the class generated from POJO's but at the time of deserialization of JSON response I don't have the actual class to which I can deserialize.

```
MyClassLoader classLoader = new MyClassLoader(POJOGeneratorForJSON.class.getClassLoader());

Class parentJsonClass = classLoader.loadClass(topLevelclassName, classpathLoc);

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

byte[] jsonBytes = generator.getBytesFromURL(source);

if(jsonBytes != null){

    Object jsonObj = parentJsonClass.newInstance();
    jsonObj = mapper.readValue(jsonBytes, Class.class);
}
```

Exception I am getting is:"`com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.Class out of START_OBJECT token`"

I know that in the `mapper.readValue()` I need to provide the actual class as second argument, but dont know how. Can someone help me with a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the second argument to `readValue` you need to pass a `Class` instance defining the type of the object you want to read. It seems you are passing the type of `Class` itself. And jackson can't deserialize a `Class` object from `jsonBytes`. Something like this should work:

```
Object jsonObj = mapper.readValue(jsonBytes, parentJsonClass);
```

i.e. read an object of type `parentJsonClass` from `jsonBytes`

Comment: Thanks alot Manos ....that worked!! .... my bad. But my final need is to call the methods inside ParentJsonClass (we have object as parentJsonClass) but its of Type Class and not ParentJsonClass. Can you help on this?

Comment: You can use `Class parentJsonClass` to cast an `Object jsonObj` to that type. So if there is a method `foo()` say `parentJsonClass.cast(jsonObj).foo();`

Comment: Using above approach, i can see only Object level methods not the one in the ParentJsonClass class. My problem is that I even don't know the methods in the class there.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20366356/1413133 try this to list public methods of a class with reflection. Or try `parentJsonClass.getMethods()`